# EntityFramework and bad table name

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a EntityFramework repository from an existing database. The problem is that one of the tables is called "System". This causes all sorts of strange compilation error from the EF generated code, as System naturally is not a good class name.

Anyone have a way to get around this problem? Changing the table name is not an option in my case.

Comment: Just change the name of the entity in the model file, you don't have to stick with the defaults.

Comment: You meen the edmx file? or the generated class?

Comment: The EDMX file, this will cause new, not broken classes to be generated.

Comment: Excellent. But where is the mapping between table name and class name done? Can I change the name in the diagram and not expect it to break the sql queries?

Comment: which version of EF are you using?

Comment: latest version (6.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion simplest way to handle this issue will be not checking that particular table during import from a database structure (when you're generating edmx file), using Entity Framework as usual on every other table and for that "System" table using SqlQuery Entity's command to execute plain SQL queries. You may also try to edit edmx (after generating it excluding "System" table) and add this table manually with different name if it's possible, but faster will be the first scenario.

Answer (score 0):

try in this way. Go to your `ContexName.Context.cs` file

where you have the bad declaration like this

```
public virtual DbSet<System> System{ get; set; }
```

right click on `<System>` -->Go to Declaration

then change

```
public partial class System
```

into

```
public partial class SystemTable
```

finally change

```
 public virtual DbSet<System> System{ get; set; }
```

into

```
public virtual DbSet<SystemTable> SystemTable{ get; set; }
```

Note that Manual changes to this files will be overwritten if the code is regenerated, so you every time need to redo this operation.